# 'class MainClass' has no member named 'procent

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class MainClass{
    public:
        virtual void getData() = 0;
        virtual void printData() = 0;
};
class Car : public MainClass{
    private:
        int hp;
        int motor;
    public:
        Car(int _hp = 0, int _motor = 0){
            hp = _hp;
            motor = _motor;
        }
        ~Car(){
            cout << "The program is over";
        }
        void getData(){
            cout << "HorsePower = ";
            int _hp;
            cin >> _hp;
            hp = _hp;
            cout << "Motor = ";
            int _motor;
            cin >> _motor;
            motor = _motor;
        }
        void printData(){
            cout << "HorsePower = " << hp << '\n';
            cout << "Motor = " << motor << '\n';
        }
        float procent(){
            return float(motor) / hp;
        }
};
int main()
{
    MainClass *p = new Car;
    p -> getData();
    p -> printData();
    cout << p -> procent();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty new with oop concepts so why do I get the error from title and how can i solve it? I tried to put virtual float procent() = 0 in MainClass, but then i should use this function in every class that i would create next and I dont want this.

Comment: You say you don’t want to have to add procent to every class that you derive from MainClass, but then what would you want to happen when p points to one of those classes and it calls procent? Understanding what you want to happen in that situation should help guide you to the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`procent()` is not a member of `class MainClass`.

The pointee type of `p` is `MainClass`.

Hence, you can only access what is known in `MainClass`.
That the pointer `p` actually holds an address of a `Car` instance doesn't count for this.

`getData()` and `printData()` are known but `procent()` not. (It's part of the derived `class Car`.)

That you can access `Car`s overridden `getData()` and `printData()` by the `MainClass` pointer `p` is a result of the (wonderful world of) polymorphy i.e. they are `virtual`.

So, this is a potential solution – to make `procent()` a `virtual` member function of `MainClass` as well.

---

There is still another solution but it should be used as last resort only:

You can use [dynamic_cast()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to check whether/that `p` holds actually a pointer to an instance of `class Car`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class MainClass{
    public:
        virtual void getData() = 0;
        virtual void printData() = 0;
};
class Car : public MainClass{
    private:
        int hp;
        int motor;
    public:
        Car(int _hp = 0, int _motor = 0){
            hp = _hp;
            motor = _motor;
        }
        ~Car(){
            cout << "The program is over";
        }
        void getData(){
            cout << "HorsePower = ";
            int _hp;
            cin >> _hp;
            hp = _hp;
            cout << "Motor = ";
            int _motor;
            cin >> _motor;
            motor = _motor;
        }
        void printData(){
            cout << "HorsePower = " << hp << '\n';
            cout << "Motor = " << motor << '\n';
        }
        float procent(){
            return float(motor) / hp;
        }
};
int main()
{
    MainClass *p = new Car;
    p -> getData();
    p -> printData();
    if (Car *pCar = dynamic_cast<Car*>(p)) {
      cout << pCar -> procent();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
HorsePower = 300
Motor = 6
HorsePower = 300
Motor = 6
0.02
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60bc24040c3eb8f)

The solution with `dynamic_cast` may be preferable for large class inheritance trees where it's merely impractical to add `virtual` member functions to the base class for any (exotic) specific feature of derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because your trying to access the `procent()` method in the MainClass object. To resolve this, you need to add it as a virtual method in the MainClass and override it in the Car object.

Plus make sure to delete the allocated memory.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MainClass{
    public:
        virtual void getData() = 0;
        virtual void printData() = 0;
        virtual void procent() = 0;
};

class Car : public MainClass {
    private:
        int hp;
        int motor;
    public:
        Car(int _hp = 0, int _motor = 0){
            hp = _hp;
            motor = _motor;
        }
        ~Car(){
            cout << "The program is over";
        }

        void getData() override {
            cout << "HorsePower = ";
            int _hp;
            cin >> _hp;
            hp = _hp;
            cout << "Motor = ";
            int _motor;
            cin >> _motor;
            motor = _motor;
        }

        void printData() override {
            cout << "HorsePower = " << hp << '\n';
            cout << "Motor = " << motor << '\n';
        }

        float procent() override {
            return float(motor) / hp;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MainClass *p = new Car;
    p -> getData();
    p -> printData();
    cout << p -> procent();

    delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

The reason for the error is that when you assign the data of the derived class to the base class pointer, the data accessed from the base class pointer is treated as if its from the base class. And since the method `procent()` is not available in it, the error is flagged.

***TIP:*** 
Even though stating `override` in the overridden method is not necessary, it'll definitely increase the readability of your code.